# How to correct for "Error in nullmodel(comm, method) : could not find function "list2env" in the vegan package

Tags: r

I'm busy exploring the package *vegan* for R, using it to calculate nestedness of community matrices and null models. I'm particularly interested in using the permat functions as well as Oecosimu.

However, when running my program I obtained the following errors:

> Error in nullmodel(comm, method) : could not find function "list2env"
>   Error in nullmodel(m, ALGO) : could not find function "list2env"

I then even ran an example (given below) of how to use these functions given by the R help function, and even these examples gave the same error. Am I suppose to import something else in order to use these functions or how do I go about fixing this?

Examples:

```
m <- matrix(c(
   1,3,2,0,3,1,
   0,2,1,0,2,1,
   0,0,1,2,0,3,
   0,0,0,1,4,3
   ), 4, 6, byrow=TRUE)

x1 <- permatswap(m, "quasiswap")

summary(x1)

x2 <- permatfull(m)

summary(x2)

x3 <- permatfull(m, "none", mtype="prab")

x3$orig  

summary(x3)

x4 <- permatfull(m, strata=c(1,1,2,2))

summary(x4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this is a bug in the development version of Vegan on R-Forge. We were failing to declare a dependency on R versions >= 2.12 in `DESCRIPTION`. I have checked in the relevant change to the source tree to fix this but it will take a day or so before the tarball and binaries are rebuilt by R-Forge.

That said, you should probably update your R to something more recent. Or use the versions of those functions provided in Vegan 2.0-x on CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

`list2env` is part of R base, which means it comes with the distribution, not in an add-on package. So if you don't have it you're probably either running an old version of R or have a broken installation. The example worked fine for me, with R 2.12.1 and vegan 2.1-0.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me without an error message

The most probable cause of your error is your using old versions of `R`, `vegan` or `permute`

The [R news for changes](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/NEWS) says

> CHANGES IN R VERSION 2.12.0: NEW FEATURES:
>
> ```
> o New list2env() utility function as an inverse of
>   as.list(<environment>) and for fast multi-assign() to existing
>   environment.  as.environment() is now generic and uses list2env()
>   as list method.
> ```
>
> CHANGES IN R VERSION 2.12.1: BUG FIXES:
>
> ```
> o When list2env() created an environment it was missing a PROTECT
>   call and so was vulnerable to garbage collection.
> ```
>
> CHANGES IN R VERSION 2.13.0: NEW FEATURES:
>
> ```
> o list2env(envir = NULL) defaults to hashing (with a suitably sized
>   environment) for lists of more than 100 elements.
> ```

So update your version of R and the packages and try again.